# How to show only relevant weeks in PrimeNg's p-calendar?

Tags: primeng, primeng-calendar

I'm using the inline version of `p-calendar` and [in several month a redundant week is shown on the calendar (image attached on this link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO5yj.png)

I'm using `p-calendar` in the following way:

```
  <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="currentTime" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" placeholder="all"
              [locale]="'general.time.calendar.lang-definitions' | translate" [selectOtherMonths]="true"
    class="my-calendar" [showIcon]="true" [defaultDate]="serverLocalTime" [showButtonBar]="true"
    [inline]="true" clearButtonStyleClass="calendar-hide-button" todayButtonStyleClass="calendar-today-button">
<p-footer>
   <!-- Something -->
</p-footer>
```

Does anyone knows how to make `p-calendar` show only relevant weeks?

Comment: Do you want to hide the marked days from your attached image or only show the marked days from the attached image?

Comment: I want to hide them. The current behavior is that the calendar always show 6 lines, even if it is not needed.